# Excel table to json converter

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel table with contains the following data:
format:

```
mainheading:    
   subheading:
       mandatory:
         fieldname:
           type:
           description:
           function:
       optional:
          type
          description
```

again cycle repeats. Need to loop through that excel and required for

Need a optimum way to do it. can anyone help how to deal with this excel to json conversion

Comment: Download the json.bas https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser and use it to create your json. I t will be much more maintainble in the future

Comment: Your code is from https://winmundo.com/need-to-convert-an-excel-sheet-to-its-json-format-in-vba/ which seems like a completely different problem.   FYI if you just paste code from elsewhere without giving any attribution we think you wrote it your self and folks may be less likely to help out (since it will appear to already know enough to solve it yourself...)

Comment: Just wanted few steps to get started. Can anyone help